# Unable to do scraping href on jquery object

Tags: jquery, python

Can I scrape a jquery object?
I actually want to get all href links from the jquery object. 
How could I achieve that? 
I just learned Python web scraping less than one week ago from YouTube and the Internet.

```
url_1='http://ws.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/announcements_listing_f.html?_=1449326650932&callback=jQuery16208050466175191104_1449326525662&page_category=company&category=FA&sub_category=all&all_gm=&alphabetical=All&board=&sector=&date_from=&date_to=&company=5218&page=&testing='

#Standard url request
    req = urllib.request.Request(url_1, headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(respData, 'html.parser')
    #soup.prettify()

    pattern=re.compile("href")
    links = soup.find_all(text=pattern)
    print(links)
```

I still cannot get all the links.
It returns with many `\\\n` from `\n`. Why does this happen?
Should I convert them into string?

I tried using

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
print(links)
```

but it returns `[]`. Why is that so?

I can obtain href link in the normal webpage, but not on the jquery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not debug your code, but from the response of the `url` you provided, I can see that the html content is a value, in a key value pair of the object. So for making a good soup, you need to extract that html first. Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) you can do it like following.

```
import re
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url='http://ws.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/announcements_listing_f.html?_=1449326650932&callback=jQuery16208050466175191104_1449326525662&page_category=company&category=FA&sub_category=all&all_gm=&alphabetical=All&board=&sector=&date_from=&date_to=&company=5218&page=&testing='
pat = re.compile(r'\(\s*(\{[\s,\w,\W]*\})\s*\)')

r = requests.get(url)
js_obj = json.loads(pat.search(r.text).group(1))

soup = BeautifulSoup(js_obj.get('html'), 'lxml')

links = map(lambda a: a.get('href'), soup.find_all('a'))

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

This will yield a output like:

```
/market/listed-companies/list-of-companies/plc-profile.html?stock_code=5218
/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/4867445
/market/listed-companies/list-of-companies/plc-profile.html?stock_code=5218
/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/4772849
....
```

Comment: js_obj = json.loads(pat.search(r.content).group(1))
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: I got the above error. why sometime has this error. Is it because i using the latest python3.5? I use pycharm4.5 free edition.

Comment: `url='http://ws.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/announcements_listing_f.html?_=1449326650932&callback=jQuery16208050466175191104_1449326525662&page_category=company&category=FA&sub_category=all&all_gm=&alphabetical=All&board=&sector=&date_from=&date_to=&company=5218&page=&testing='
pat = re.compile(r'\(\s*(\{[\s,\w,\W]*\})\s*\)')

r = requests.get(url)
js_obj=json.loads(pat.search(r.content).group(1))

soup = BeautifulSoup(js_obj.get('html'))

links = map(lambda a: a.get('href'), soup.find_all('a'))

print(links)`

Comment: ok... it requires to install lxml `pip install --upgrade lxml` but got error

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)

Comment: use `html.parser` parser. `soup = BeautifulSoup(js_obj.get('html'), 'html.parser')`

Comment: Thanks Salman Wahed! it solved the problem! it seems that i still have long way to learn the python. need to pick up json & requests command